# What does the "different width due to prototype" warning mean?

Tags: c, warnings, char, width

The code generating the warning, passing argument 1 of 'isHex' with different width due to prototype:

```
/* Checks if a character is either 0-9 or A-F */
int isHex(char ch) {
    return isdigit(ch) || (ch >= 65 && ch <= 70);
}

/* Checks if a string only contains numeric characters or A-F */
int strIsHex(char * str) {
    char *ch;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    for(ch=str;ch<(str+len);ch++) {
        if (!isHex(*ch)) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

What does this mean, shouldn't the `char` values be the be same width? How can I cast them to the same width to prevent this warning?

By the way, the gcc command was: `gcc.exe -std=c99 -fgnu89-inline -pedantic-errors -Wno-long-long -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -fshort-enums -gstabs -l"C:\program files\quincy\mingw\include" -o main.o -c main.c`

I can't remove any of the warning options from gcc as one of the marking criteria for an assignment is that there are no errors or warnings with this command.

Thanks.

Comment: Needz more whitespace...

Comment: Why not use [`isxdigit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isxdigit.html)?

Comment: isHex was simply used out of ignorance of isxdigit existing - using it solves my problem, and appears to be much neater. 

However, before I start making my own case-insensitive strncmp, does one already exist?

Comment: How about [`strncasecmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncasecmp.html)? And I'll throw in a [handy bookmark](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/index.html) too. I think `strcasecmp` is an old BSDism though.

Comment: Gee, it really seems like I keep re-inventing the wheel, and I thought i was getting good at this. :(

Anyway, I've changed it to `strncasecmp`, but gcc keeps warning that it's an `implict delaration of strncasecmp` even though I've got `<string.h>` included and it is in the MingGW headers. Any ideas?

Comment: @mu: your handy bookmark is old(ish) (POSIX 2004). Try the [POSIX 2008 bookmark](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/index.html) :)

Comment: `strings.h` is the right header for `strncasecmp` (note the extra `s` at the end).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the -Wconversion flag on the command line. It pops up "if a prototype causes a type conversion that is different from what would happen to the same argument in the absence of a prototype." Since the default integral argument type is int, you can't declare `isHex(char ch)` without triggering this.

You have two options, I think: declare `isHex(int ch)` and let it be widened in the call or else declare it `isHex(char *ch)` and change the call.

P.S. If this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: I think `isHex(int)` is his only option. That avoids fighting with the standard promotions and also matches all the standard "is" things in `ctype.h`.

Comment: @mu: there's no need to match with `ctype.h` since the OP always passes `char`. The functions/macros in `ctype.h` also operate work for the `int` constant `EOF`.

Comment: Er?  What `gcc` version is this?  That's `-Wtraditional-conversion` in 4.4 at least; `-Wconversion` doesn't include prototypes, only implicit conversions.  (Which may mean the assigment requires a newer `gcc`.)

Comment: Users writing their own hex functions really do give away that its homework don't they :P

Comment: Homework or not, this is a good question with a non-obvious answer.  It certainly wasn't a "plz give me teh codez" question.

Comment: @geekosaur - I think it may depend on the specific build of gcc, not just the version. See, for example, [this thread from August](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-08/msg00206.html) on the gcc-help mailing list archive. Since he's using `gcc.exe`, it's a good bet this is a Windows distribution.

Comment: @Ted: looks to me like they're talking about a signed/unsigned conversion in that thread, which *is* covered by `-Wconversion`.  As I said, complaining about prototypes changing pre-ANSI behavior (`(char)` being passed as `(int)` in K&R C) while also requiring ANSI behavior is not sensible.  In fact, some 22 years on, I think one can safely pretend K&R C didn't exist in beginning C classes.

Comment: @larsman: And, AFAIK, they also take `int` to avoid the old school type conversion issues. I suspect they work with `EOF` because someone noticed that they already took `int` so why make them work with `EOF` too. I don't have a historical treatise on `ctype.h` handy though so I could be wrong.

Comment: @mu: It was so that the `ctype` macros would handle the full range of `getchar()`, including `EOF`. Although it's not that far off: in the Bad Old Days, a fertile source of cross-platform errors was programs assigning `getchar()` into a `(char)`, which (this being before anyone cared about non-ASCII) worked fine when `(char)` was signed and caused bizarre errors when the same program was built where `(char)` was unsigned.  One way to discourage this was to make the things most often used with `getchar()` also demand `(int)`, so using `(char)` for intermediate variables would produce warnings.

Comment: @geekosaur: Thanks. You're bringing back nightmares of making a massive pile of C (half of which was still K&R without prototypes) work on ten different flavors of unix and DOS and Win3.1 with 12 different compilers. Thanks, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @mu; 'Sokay, I was remembering more than a few of those myself as I wrote it, from back when I was insane enough to force NOS.EXE run on Linux, Solaris, and SCO Unix.

Comment: @Ted: Hi, thanks for the help. I didn't know there was a "homework" tag - in the future I'll tag it as such if it helps, but this was more a problem I encountered rather than the homework is to fix this.