gcc compilation error on simple short int function call with flag -Werror=traditional-conversion
Compiling this C program with gcc 11.4.0 and -Werror=traditional-conversion raises an error:
short int f(short int x);

short int f(short int x) {
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    short int a = 0;
    f(a);

    return 0;
}

error: passing argument 1 of ‘f’ with different width due to prototype
Assuming that I can't change the function's signature because it comes from a library, is there a way to change the calling code to make the error go away?
I did try several kind of integer types for the a variable but to no avail. I would not expect the error to appear because the variable and the function's parameter prototype type are the same (short int). It looks to me like a false positive but it may be related to some implicit default promotion. I would rather find a solution that doesn't make me remove this compilation flag.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509406/what-does-the-different-width-due-to-prototype-warning-mean

Just don't enable that error. The thing it's complaining about is not really an error.

It's warning about something that would be a problem if you didn't have a function prototype in scope (because short int would be converted to int by default promotions). But since you do, it's not a problem.

IMHO that error is useless and it will produce lots of false positives like that. The purpose seems to be to ensure compatibility with K&R C, which is not something you should worry about over 40 years later.

Why do you want to do that? It is completely useless.

If you have no choice but to compile with this flag, you can disable it for a few lines using a pragma:
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtraditional-conversion"
    f(a);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop


This will get quite tedious if they have to put this pragma around every call to functions that take an argument smaller than int.

I was hoping there would exists a code syntax to help the compiler see that this was a false positive, but if it has to be a compiler ignore comment, so be it. The method I was trying to call is htons. Thanks!
